# The particle system when adding a collection

Tags: system

there is such a problem when adding trees through the particle system, they appear not in the right place, but below, how can this be fixed?
[image]

Comment: 1) Check where is the origin of trees. Is it shifted along the trunk ? 2) Do you have other modifiers for this object ? If so, check in "Source" (almost at the top of the ParticleSystem editor in the right panel of your picture), and select "Use Modifier Stack".

Comment: please provide blend file, because you didn't provide all necessary informations to help you. thx.

Comment: If you moved to the he original mesh in edit mode away from the origin(orange dot) it could give this effect, you could move it again in edit mode or fix the origin the bottom part